# Среднее значение в Python: "name 'a' is not defined

Tags: python, математика, суммирование

Подскажите как правильно исправить код:

```
def srsumm(n,a=0,b=0):
    for i in n:
        a=a+i
        b+=1
        return a, b
print(a,b)#для проверки
```

P.S: Python говорит, что ***"name 'a' is not defined"*** переменная "a" не найдена.

Comment: И правильно говорит, переменная a существует только в функции srsumm()

Comment: `def srsumm(n): return sum(n) / len(n)`

Comment: вы можете [`statistics.mean()` использовать, чтобы найти среднее значение](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во первых, как вам правильно указали, переменные `a` и `b` существуют только внутри функции, они недоступны снаружи.

Так как вы их возвращаете как результат функции, то достаточно просто сохранить результат функции и вывести его на экран:

```
total, count = srsumm(iterable)
print(total, count)
```

Есть ещё проблема в том, что функция возвращает результат сразу же после первой итерации по циклу, что приводит к тому, что учитывается только первый элемент последовательности.

Для того, чтобы исправить это, стоит уменьшить отступ у оператора `return`:

```
for i in n:
    a += i
    b += 1
return a, b
```